# Dockerizing VueJS with Nginx Cannot Access Backend Application with http://localhost

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js

I followed [this section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example) to create a docker image for my vuejs application. I could access my backend application(spring boot) with localhost `http://localhost:8081` in development mode. I cannot access it from my dockerized vuejs application. It calls the URL with OPTIONS method and it returns (failed) status. I already implemented cors filter in my backend application.

I build the image with `docker build -t vuejs/frontend .` and run it with
`docker run -td -p 8082:80 --rm --name frontend vuejs/frontend`. I can access my homepage. I cannot access my homepage if I set `--net="host"` in `docker run ...` command. What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully call my backend api?

Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

app = express();
app.use(serveStatic('./dist'));
const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;
app.listen(port);
console.log('server started ', port);
```

Docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                            NAMES
6727648105dc        vuejs/frontend               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                                                                                                                         frontend
221c6554f99e        java/backend                 "java -Djava.securit…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                                                                                                         backend
73d29d1e1986        database/phoenix_hbase:4.10.0   "/bin/sh -c /opt/hba…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60000->60000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60010->60010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60020->60020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60030->60030/tcp   docker-hbase
```

Comment: you can access inside container by container name, all containers are inside one local network

Comment: @bxN5 Backend docker name is `backend`. Should I call it `http://backend:8081`, because I inspected backend docker and `IPAddress` was empty. I ran it with `--net="host"`.

Comment: Yes, try to login inside container and ping another container by name

Comment: @bxN5 I think I am unable to do this. I tried `docker exec -it frontend ping backend` it says `ping: bad address 'backend'`. Is that it?

Comment: show pls output of docker ps command

Comment: @bxN5 I pasted in the question. I also managed to run the frontend with `--net="host"`